# Referencing piped value in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to count the number of word-occurrences in a string. The implementation is questionable, but lets use it to demonstrate my problem:

```
  def count(sentence) do
    words = String.split(sentence)
    occurrences = Enum.map(words, fn w -> {w, Enum.count(words, &(&1 == w))} end)
    Map.new(occurrences)
  end
```

I would like to achieve the same result as above, but using pipes instead of intermediate result variables:

```
def count(sentence) do
    sentence
    |> String.split
    |> Enum.map(fn w -> {w, Enum.count(???)} end)
    |> Map.new
  end
```

Is it possible to reference the piped in value in the Enum.count function? Or do i have to use an intermediate variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put an anonymous function in the pipeline:

```
def count(sentence) do
  sentence
  |> String.split
  |> (fn words -> Enum.map(words, fn w -> {w, Enum.count(words, &(&1 == w))} end) end).()
  |> Map.new
end
```

```
iex(1)> count("foo bar baz foo")
%{"bar" => 1, "baz" => 1, "foo" => 2}
```

Answer (score 6):

Though the @Dogbert’s answer is perfectly correct, I would add a sidenote: it seems that as soon as you need the pipe-out value twice, you’re likely doing it wrong. The above example might be rewritten as:

```rb
def count(sentence) do
  sentence
  |> String.split
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn e, acc ->
    Map.put(acc, e, (Map.get(acc, e) || 0) + 1)
  end)
end
```

or in many other ways, that reduce an amount of loops involved (and, hence, the *big-O* of the whole function.)

---

**Modern era update:** starting with `v1.8`, [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension has a [`reduce:` keyword parameter](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-reduce-option), that makes the above even easier to grasp:

```rb
def count(sentence) do
  for word <- String.split(sentence), reduce: %{} do
    %{^word => count} = acc -> %{acc | word => count + 1}
    acc -> Map.put(acc, word, 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: (I did not suggest a better algorithm in my answer as it looked like OP knew that already and was just using that code as an example as he said "The implementation is questionable, but lets use it to demonstrate my problem".)

Comment: My point is: under no circumstances it might be unavoidable necessary to use a piped var twice.

Comment: My final solution used reduce aswell, but what interested me was the problem Dogbert adressed. That being said i think that the anonymous function approach is confusing and should definitely be replaced by something like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Map.update achieves this in a pretty elegant way. I saw Jose Valim himself use this at Lambda Days 2017.

```
  def count_words(words) do
    words
    |> String.split()
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, &count/2)
  end

 def count(word, map) do
  Map.update(map, word, 1, & &1 + 1)
 end
```

```
iex(1)> Word.count_words("I know we can yes we can can")
%{"I" => 1, "can" => 3, "know" => 1, "we" => 2, "yes" => 1}
```