# How to access the parameter passed through pipe operator in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a series of transformation on `Plug.Conn` that requires access to intermediary results.

```
n_conn = 
  conn
  |> Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params()
nn_conn =
  n_conn
  |> assign(:result, inspect(Timestamp.convert_datetime(n_conn.params)))
nn_conn
|> send_resp(200, nn_conn.assigns.result)
|> halt()
```

I need `n_conn` because `conn.params` is not set until `Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params()` is called. Likewise, I need `nn_conn` because `n_conn.assigns.result` is not set until `assign/3` function is called.

The code is fairly ugly. If there were a way to refer to the output of pipe operator, I could simplify it like the following. I was hoping for `&1` to work but it doesn't.

```
conn
|> Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params()
|> assign(:result, inspect(Timestamp.convert_datetime(&1.params)))
|> send_resp(200, &1.assigns.result)
|> halt()
```

Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass anonymous functions if you want to do this through only pipes, but [it's ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658251/320615). I'd reuse the name `conn` and not use pipes for single function calls:

```
conn = Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn)
conn = assign(conn, :result, inspect(Timestamp.convert_datetime(conn.params)))
conn
|> send_resp(200, conn.assigns.result)
|> halt()
```

Since you don't seem to be using `conn.assigns.result`, you could skip storing it in `assigns`:

```
conn = Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn)
result = inspect(Timestamp.convert_datetime(conn.params))
conn
|> send_resp(200, result)
|> halt()
```